# Parse Unstructured Data in Shell script/Linux

Tags: linux, shell

```
Example log : "some data7.575=tf.some data2.0=tf.some data1.23=tf.some data.."

I want to get each TF value as output. 
i.e. output should be 
TF=7.575
TF=2.0
TF=1.23
```

How can I parse this? Using Shell script (preferrable). Unix command or using Java.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit as your changes were quite substantial, rendering the existing answers invalid for the updated question. You should accept one of the answers below (or post one of your own and accept it) and ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `grep -P` command:

```
grep -oP '[\d.]+(?==tf\.some)' file
7.575
2.0
1.23
```

Or using this awk:

```
awk -F 'data|=' '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print "TF=" $i}' file
TF=7.575
TF=2.0
TF=1.23
```

Comment: Hi. I am having another issue with parsing. I want to parse the following,
x = (PHRASE) title:y
x1= (PHRASE) title:y1
...
my outout should be 
x--y
x1--y1 etc.. Can you please help?

Comment: Difficult to understand new requirements from comments. Can you edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Someone has reverted the question. I'll post a new question.